# When I show Custom XSL date in my Web Part that time it showing one day added Date.?

Tags: web-part, xslt

I am showing the custom date in my Web Part but it showing one Day added to date.
The current date field is DateTime Format, so I am showing only date it work but it showing one day added to date.

This is my Code :

```
< xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(@ActivityDate, 1033, 'MM/dd/yyyy')" />
```

It showing one day added date.

Comment: are you checked the regional language setting at your site setting, check the time zone and the selected calendar

Comment: Yes i checked and also select the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check `Site Settings : Regional Settings` , make sure that you are selected the correct `time zone` also check `calendar type`, where  there's some calendar like `Hijri` calendar can add one day or subtract one day.

If everything is okay, try to do the following :

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext(string(@ActivityDate))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime($date, 1033, 'MM/dd/yyyy')" />
```

where `FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext` format `@ActivityDate` based on your current SharePoint context settings .